# I have to write apple ID every time when turn on my mac

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, apple-id

When I restart my Mac every time i have to add Apple ID to iCloud (It happened after update to macOS Sierra). A fullscreen window and after typing Apple ID are terms and conditions.

And another similar situation that happened to me
I have icons in my deck, specifically Siri, maps, photos and iBook. When I want to remove it from deck after restart or turn on my Mac every icon is back.

Comment: Sounds like your preferences/settings are not being saved.  Can you make a new acct (with or without iCloud) and see if it happens there?  If not, the "good" news is it's not the OS.  The bad news is that it's your original acct, and you might have to start removing Preferences to see what's corrupt or unwriteable.

Comment: I played with certificates inside Keychain Access. it is possible that I broke something?